# Media queries not being read in chrome in mobile debugging view

Tags: google-chrome, media-queries

I am experiencing very strange behavior with Chrome. It is not picking up media queries at certain sizes when it is in the mobile debugging view.

For example the following works in mobile view:

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    #cliff {
      background-color: red; } 
    }
```

but this doesn't work

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 979px) {
    #cliff {
      background-color: red; } 
    }
```

You will see the difference is only one pixel. Then if I come out of the mobile debugging view and change the screen size it works. Can anyone advise, or know of any reason that this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have this in the header?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Also, maybe changing the format will help. This works for me:

```
@media (max-width:980px){
     //Styles
}
```